# How can I navigate from a windows phone 7 app to (or point to) a pdf file which is hosted in web server

Tags: windows-phone-7, pdf, hyperlink

How can I navigate from a windows phone 7 app to (or point to) a pdf file which is hosted in web server. I want to open the pdf file in the pdf viewer for WP7 app (I believe the current IE for WP7 would not be able to open a pdf file).

Something like

HuperLinkButton.NavigateUri = "http://mypdfserver/a1.pdf"

would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to raise a WebBrowser Task & point to the PDF URI. IE is then going to ask the user to download the Adobe Reader if they do not have it installed. Something like this:

```
WebBrowserTask browseToPDF = new WebBrowserTask();
browseToPDF.URL = "<server-URI><FileName>.pdf";
browseToPDF.Show();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both your suggestion and the HyperLinkButton.NavigateUri = "http://mypdfserver/a1.pdf" is working.